# How can I read the info of a media file using visual c++?

Tags: visual-c++, video, windows-7

Is there a way to read the info (fps, bitrate, duration, codecs required, etc.) of a media file (avi, mp4, mkv, etc.) on windows using visual studio c++?

I managed to play various files (which I actually don't even want) using directshow (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I don't know how to only get the information from the file.

Edit: I got it working like this...

```
int             height, width, framerate, bitrate;
LARGE_INTEGER   duration;

// initialize the COM library
CoInitialize(NULL);

// 
IPropertyStore* store = NULL;
SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName(L"E:\\test.avi", NULL, GPS_DEFAULT, __uuidof(IPropertyStore), (void**)&store);

PROPVARIANT variant;

store->GetValue(PKEY_Media_Duration, &variant);
duration = variant.hVal;
store->GetValue(PKEY_Video_FrameHeight, &variant);
height = variant.lVal;
store->GetValue(PKEY_Video_FrameWidth, &variant);
width = variant.lVal;
store->GetValue(PKEY_Video_FrameRate, &variant);
framerate = variant.lVal;
store->GetValue(PKEY_Video_TotalBitrate, &variant);
bitrate = variant.lVal;
// 
store->Release();
//
CoUninitialize();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain this information via DirectShow, however if you don't need the playback/streaming pipeline and you are on Windows 7, then you possibly have a better alternate option to get the data from shell properties - those supplying data to display in additional columns of Windows explorer.

- [`SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gets you property store
- MSDN entry point for [Shell Metadata Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff384868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- Code snippet: [How to use the IPropertyStore to obtain `Media_Duration`?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b6b91a57-a899-4b68-a4c7-3e57997e3cb2/how-to-use-the-ipropertystore-to-obtain-mediaduration?forum=vcgeneral)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the [MediaInfo SDK](http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Support/SDK)?  You can get extensive information about all of the audio and video streams available in the container, including codec specifics, as well as everything you were asking about.

Their getting started guide and reference documentation are here:
http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Support/SDK/Quick_Start
http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Support/SDK/More_Info

Code is available at their SourceForge page [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mediainfo/?source=directory).